# Getting a get error when I redirect on my SPA, hosted with amplify

Tags: reactjs, vite, aws-amplify

I have recently built my vite proyect with amplify. The project manages to build well, but regarding redirects, it crashes and stops, throwing me the following error:
[image]

My build profile is:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build --prod
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: /dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

And the proyect structre the one vite provides:

```
dist
|__assets
|
|__index.html
```

I am in fact adding the custom redirect for SPA's `</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>` yet on redirects (made with react-router-dom, my pagre crashes)

Comment: I haven't hosted with amplify but a lot of the time with SPA you need to tell it not to look for other pages and always stay at the root page. To me it looks like it is looking for a new page that doesn't exist, because it doesn't as its an SPA.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this!

Suprisingly by adding this in my defineConfig (on my `vite.config.js`) file it worked:

```
base: '<your url link>',
```

I documented this process in the following article: https://dev.to/muvinai/building-and-distributing-vitejs-projects-with-amplify-hdd